# Trying to fully understand this function before moving to my next lesson

Tags: javascript, jquery

Question 1. is "makeGrid" just a random name that was given to this function or is there some sort of functionality behind it like "math.random"?

Question 2. "$('.square').css({'width': squareSize, 'height': squareSize});" If the loop already made a Y row to 16 and a X row to 16 and appended it to the container isn't the mission accomplished? Why is this line making the width and height of .square 45 when that was already established in the CSS?

JQUERY

```
var numberSquares = 16;
var squareSize = 45;

function makeGrid() {
   for (var x = 0; x < numberSquares; x++) {
      for (var y = 0; y < numberSquares; y++) {
         $("<div class='square'></div>").appendTo('.container');
      }
   }
   $('.square').css({'width': squareSize, 'height': squareSize});
}
```

CSS

```
.container {
   background-color: white;
   border: 5px solid black;
   border-radius: 5px;
   width: 720px;
   height: 720px;
   margin: 20px auto;
}
.square {
   background-color: white;
   height: 45px;
   width: 45px;
   float: left;
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) Some random name, 2) changing sq size in code allows you different size squares without changing source css

Comment: So basically the CSS height and with could be deleted since they are being set with JQuery?

Comment: not deleted, overridden